# Cómo copiar el texto de commit en Sourcetree Mac OS?

Tags: macos, sourcetree

¿Cómo puedo ver y copiar todo el texto asociado a un Commit en SourceTree Mac OS?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Bajo la pestaña del gráfico de los commits, se haya una ventana que describe los archivos modificados por commit, ahi también se describe el comentario del commit, donde puedes copiar el texto:

[image: capture]

Comment: No me muestra esa sección.

Answer (score 0):

Si no les muestra la sección, como lo menciona Levi Arista en la respuesta anteriormente, encontré esta forma:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]